# Role based Public Group Access

Tags: administration

**Case1:** I have a user who has the role of "**US Exec**" and has no pubic groups.

**Case2:** For the same user when I change the role to "**SA Exec**" suddenly I see 10 public groups appearing.

I know when a role is added to a public group, the user when assigned with the role automatically gets the public group. However, in this case, when I go the public groups, I find no mention of the role.

**Q:** Is there a way we can check in SFDC how a user is getting access to a public group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to `User` details and in the `Public Group Membership` related list you will see the list of Public groups where user is member.

Here most important part is `Reason for Membership` column where values can be `Group Member` or `Manager of Group Member`.

[image: User_public group]

> `Group Member` means `User` is directly assigned to that public group.
>
> `Manager of Group Member` means that uses is assigned to a Role lets say Role A which is above in role hierarchy of Role B. This Role B is assigned the in public group 'Testing Team'. So, because of the Role hierarchy user will be assigned to this `Testing Team` as a part of `Manager of Group Member`